# Adjust multiple texts from labels in for each loop c# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, foreach

I have a simple for each loop which is supposed to fill multiple labels in my form with each the string from the result in that list (result.naampartij). Now I would like to use `i` to indicate which label I want to fill so that every label has the "naampartij" of that result. Like so:

```
        int i = 0;

        foreach (var result in results)
        {            

            i++;
            label[i].Text = result.naampartij;

        }
```

When i do this, visual studio registers `label[i]` as a name, not as `label1` `label2` `label3` etc as the loop goes on.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve, but can't you just use a for loop instead foreach?

Comment: C# doesn't work like that.  You may be able to use reflection to do this, but it would be far simpler to just build a List or array with the reference to the Labels that you want to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens with XAML is this:

For example:

the xaml in PageView.xaml:

```
<Label
    x:Name="Geronimo"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    Text="Hello"
    VerticalOptions="Center" />
```

When it is built, a generated C# file PageView.xaml.g.cs (that you don't modify manually) is generated. That file contains:

```
public partial class PageView
```

and

```
private global::Xamarin.Forms.Label Geronimo;
```

and

```
Geronimo = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.Label>(this, "Geronimo");
```

In PageView.xaml.cs (into which you put your own code), the remainder of the partial class called PageView is defined. In that class, you can use the Label Geronimo to do things such as:

```
Geronimo.Text = "Here we go";
```

So, what happens when `x:Name` is used in XAML is that a class is created (formed from two partial classes) that has a member variable with the specified name. So, if you work purely in C#, the equivalent is that you simply have a member variable with the desired name. w

As a workaround,you could create a stacklayout to wrap it.

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="layout">

</StackLayout>
```

then in your behind code :

```
foreach (var result in results)
    {            


        Label label = new Label();
        label.Text = result.naampartij;
        layout.Children.Add(label);
    }
```

and find the label by

```
Label label1 = (Label)layout.Children[0];
Label label2 = (Label)layout.Children[1];
 ...
```